# Is it harder to spoof (adversarial examples) a model trained to optimize a proper scoring rule than an improper scoring rule?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, scoring-rules, adversarial-example

The way I figure, if we train a model to stick points on the correct side of a threshold like $0.5$, then all we have to do is tweak a $1$ with a predicted probability of $0.51$ to give a predicted probability of $0.49$, and we have tricked the classifier. The features for the $0.49$ item are unlikely to be much different from the features for the $0.51$ item, yet we have changed the predicted category.

However, the predicted probability is only a tiny bit different!

I want to leave it a bit vague what I mean by "harder" to create an adversarial example, but is it reasonable to conclude to models developed to optimize proper scoring rules and output probabilities are harder to spoof?